# How to get xwayland listen in TCP4 port

Tags: 22.04, wayland

I have just installed a fresh Ubuntu 22.04. It's running Wayland with no problem.

I have no experience with Wayland (I'm X generation ;-) )

If I run xclock, runs fine.

```
echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

But, as I want to run remote clients, I need the X server listening in TCP.
I have tried to set

```
export DISPLAY=192.168.1.10:0
```

and then xclock reports "`Can't open DISPLAY`"

I already tried `xhost +`. Googling is not helping.

Any suggestion or link to configuration files will be helpful